# Can't decrypt file: expected public key

Tags: bash, encryption, cron, gnupg

I try to decrypt file using following command:

```
gpg --batch --no-tty --yes --always-trust --primary-keyring /root/.gnupg/secring.gpg -o file.csv --passphrase  -d file.csv.asc
```

It work fine, But when I run it in cron I get following error message:

```
gpg: expected public key but found secret key - must stop
```

What can I do to get it running in cron?

Comment: More something for superuser. But does cron have enough permissions to read your file from the root account? And if so, why?

Comment: I think there is no problem with permissions. I make it in cron as root. It's something with gpg options. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't point to a keyring, but a complete GnuPG home directory using `--homedir /root/.gnupg`. `--homedir` sets the directory GnuPG is searching all other files inside.

`--primary-keyring file` can only be used for *public* keyrings, which will not help you with decryption. From `man gpg`:

```
--primary-keyring file
      Designate file as the primary public keyring. This means that newly
      imported keys (via --import or keyserver --recv-from) will go to this
      keyring.
```

Alternatively, you can use `--secret-keyring file`:

```
--secret-keyring file
      Same as --keyring but for the secret keyrings.
```

---

I'm not sure whether you need this parameter anyway: if you're running this cron job as root user, `$HOME` should already be set to `/root` and GnuPG will find its home folder without further configuration. If you're not running the cron job as root, put the keys in another location (ie., the user's home directory); giving other users read- and possibly write access to `/root` is a potential security issue.